# How to define listener port?

Tags: jms, websphere, jmeter, ibm-mq

I'm using a JMeter with **JMS Point-to-Point** sampler, and I've a MQ queue with listener port **2222** (non standard **1414**). JMeter retrieves queue connection details from IBM WebSphere Application Sever by Provider URL, and connection factory class: **com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory**

My question is: How to define that port number in to JMeter plugin? Because I've got in 
JMeter logs messages about trying to create connection to **1414**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to:

> Start by adding the sampler JMS Point-to-Point to the Point-to-Point
>   element (Add --> Sampler --> JMS Point-to-Point). Then, select the JMS
>   Point-to-Point sampler element in the tree.

and than set the property:

```
Provider URL     tcp://$HOSTNAME:$PORT
```